# how can I get a marketplace account from adyen?

Tags: adyen

I have contact the adyen contact at this link: [Adyen contact](https://www.adyen.com/de_DE/kontakt/vertrieb)

I have to enter my website but I havent a website yet because It is on developing so I have to put there a landing page. If I write adyen I need a marketplace account I am now at developing it then I get the answer the payment not fits in your website but I have wrote that I build a marketplace and havent a site now. What can I do to get the marketplace account on adyen ?